# Access Denied VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, access-denied

i m trying to build COM dll file using C# and VS2010 - framework 3.5-:

1. if i try building the project without performing Clean, it will build, however this works only before any cleaning operation, after cleaning the project i will get stuck with this error

> Error 16  Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Demo[Demo]
>   SCPP T1\bin\Debug\PrinterPlugin.dll" - access denied. Please make sure
>   you're running the application as administrator. Access to the
>   registry key
>   'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{B9162A23-45F9-47CC-80F5-FE0FE9B9E1A2}' is
>   denied.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  3912    5   PrinterPlugin

2. i have based the original files on FrameWork 4.0 then converted to 3.5 due to COM registration incompatibility. building with Framework 4.0 will build successfully but will produce "TYPELIB" file is missing while registering the library.

*further elaboration, the old PrinterPlugin works like a charm based on framework 3.5, it would register correctly, and would function with no warnings or erros of what-so-ever, these errors started popping after adding some components from another SDK that have been distributed using framework 4.0 and uses other microsoft libraries, like bidispl.dll, ReachFramework... etc.*

EDIT0

i already have tried starting the VS2010 as admin, from every location.

EDIT1

i have tried building a new project using Framework 3.5, and still facing the same error, even when executing the devenv.exe as admin from the Common7 > IDE folder.

> Error 18  Cannot register assembly
>   "C:\Users\Ameer\Desktop\projects\PrinterPlugin without resize
>   17-05-2015\printerplugin  without resize
>   10-05-2015\bin\Debug\PrinterPlugin.dll" - access denied.
>   Please make sure you're running the application as administrator.
>   Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{B9162A23-45F9-47CC-80F5-FE0FE9B9E1A2}' is
>   denied.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  3912    5   PrinterPlugin

i m guessing this is something has to do with the compatibility between the two SDKs.

Comment: Start Visual Studio as administrator to be able to register the COM component as part of the build..

Comment: already did that, i started it from the startmenu as admin, but that did not help.
Edit, just started the devenv.exe as Admin, but that did not work either.

Comment: My suggestion is then to start regedit and manually delete registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{B9162A23-45F9-47CC-80F5-FE0FE9B9E1A2}` but I now notice that there is missing a backslash after `CLSID`. Typo by you are perhaps a solution to your problem?

Comment: sadly its not that i dont know how it was erased from there, but thats not it, i tried removing the entry from the regedit but that did not work either, its probably framework incompatibility, the newer SDK is based on Fw4.0 while the old one is based on the Fw3.5. the whole project have to be built using the Fw 3.5 or it will fail to register the component.

Comment: You have a very clear error message. A process (presumably the process that builds your application) does not have access to a particular registry key that requires administrative privileges in order to be changed. This change is required when you perform a COM registration of a COM component. This has nothing to do with framework versions or SDK compatibility. You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb896645.aspx) to discover which process fails to modify the registry.